# RigidBody overlapping each other instantiated using prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leap-motion, rigid-bodies

First of all I want to say that I have already read all the related question for the problem but none of them has helped in my scenario.

**Problem:**

I am working with Unity and Leap Motion. I am actually instantiating some game object when some collision conditions are met by Leap Motion hands. Those game objects are basically atoms as in chemistry and are spheres.

So what I am doing is when someone rings two atoms closer to each other then they form molecule. For this I instantiate a molecule using prefab and make both atoms and bonds(also instantiated are cylinder in shape) as a child of the molecule game objects which are attached to atoms using **configurable joints**.

All of this is working properly but their occurs some cases when some atoms overlap each other despite having rigid body attached to them. Also I have checked that `isTrigger` is not checked on any of them.
Also once they overlap, they do not separate at all even if I try changing value from inspector while being in play mode.

Here is the screenshot of the same.

[image: Molecule]

Code is relatively big so I am only adding code for molecule formation.

```
private void createBonds(MoleculeData moleculeData, Molecule molecule)
    {
        // local coords are --> in Unity Y is going up, Z is left & X is coming out of screen.. 
        // we will always keep Y of all atoms equal to each other and move them only in XZ space/plane
        // for eg if the angle between two atoms needs to be 90 degree then one atom needs to be farther on X axis and other on Z axis 
        // basically rcos(angle) & rsin(angle) to get projection in x & z axis
        // x = rsin(angle) & z = rcos(angle)

        List<Transform> allObjects = new List<Transform>();

        int numBonds = moleculeData.bonds.Count;
        float startAngle = 0;

        var centerAtomTransform = moleculeData.centralAtom.gameObject.transform;
        allObjects.Add(centerAtomTransform);

        moleculeData.centralAtom.parentMolecule = molecule;

        centerAtomTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        centerAtomTransform.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;

        float radiusSphere = moleculeData.centralAtom.gameObject.GetComponent<SphereCollider>().radius;
        float scale = centerAtomTransform.localScale.x; // we are assuming all scales are equal (which currently are)

        float actualRadiusOfSphere = radiusSphere * scale;

        List<Bond> allBondsFormed = new List<Bond>();

        if (moleculeData.structure == StructureType.StraightLine || moleculeData.structure == StructureType.FlatTriangle || moleculeData.structure == StructureType.Triangle)
        {
            float anglePhi = 0; // this is polar angle from positive y-axis 

            List<Vector3> positionsOnSphereBoundary = new List<Vector3>();

            for (int i = 0; i < numBonds; i++)
            {
                float xPointOnSphereBoundary = actualRadiusOfSphere * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * startAngle) + Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * anglePhi);
                float yPointOnSphereBoundary = actualRadiusOfSphere * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * anglePhi);
                float zPointOnSphereBoundary = actualRadiusOfSphere * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * startAngle) + Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * anglePhi);

                var positionOnSphereBoundary = new Vector3(centerAtomTransform.position.x + xPointOnSphereBoundary, centerAtomTransform.position.y + yPointOnSphereBoundary, centerAtomTransform.position.z + zPointOnSphereBoundary);

                positionsOnSphereBoundary.Add(positionOnSphereBoundary);

                startAngle += (float)moleculeData.bondAngle;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < positionsOnSphereBoundary.Count; i++)
            {
                var directionVectorFromAtom2ToAtom1 = centerAtomTransform.position - positionsOnSphereBoundary.ElementAt(i);


                directionVectorFromAtom2ToAtom1.Normalize();

                var bondProp = moleculeData.bonds.ElementAt(i);

                if (bondProp.bondLength == 0.0)
                {
                    bondProp.bondLength = .08f;
                }

                var finalAtomTwoPos = positionsOnSphereBoundary.ElementAt(i) + directionVectorFromAtom2ToAtom1 * bondProp.bondLength;
                Transform secondAtomTransform = null;
                Atom secondAtom = null;
                if (bondProp.connectedAtomOne != moleculeData.centralAtom)
                {
                    secondAtomTransform = bondProp.connectedAtomOne.gameObject.transform;
                    secondAtom = bondProp.connectedAtomOne;
                }
                else if (bondProp.connectedAtomTwo != moleculeData.centralAtom)
                {
                    secondAtomTransform = bondProp.connectedAtomTwo.gameObject.transform;
                    secondAtom = bondProp.connectedAtomTwo;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new System.Exception("Shall not occur??");
                }

                secondAtomTransform.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;

                secondAtomTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
                secondAtomTransform.position = finalAtomTwoPos;

                #region BondStickInit
                var bondStick = (bondProp.subType == SubBondType.Triple) ? Instantiate(tripleBondStickPrefab) : (bondProp.subType == SubBondType.Double) ? Instantiate(doubleBondStickPrefab) : Instantiate(bondStickPrefab); //Intantiate a bond stick between the atoms

                bondStick.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;

                var bond = bondStick.GetComponent<Bond>(); //Get the bond component of the bondstick
                bond.SetAtoms(moleculeData.centralAtom, secondAtom); //Add atoms to the bondstick
                bond.InitBondStick(moleculeData.centralAtom.transform, secondAtom.transform, bondProp.bondLength, actualRadiusOfSphere); //Initialize the bond stick
                bond.SetBondType(bondProp.type, bondProp.subType);
                allObjects.Add(bondStick.transform);
                allObjects.Add(secondAtomTransform);
                allBondsFormed.Add(bond);
                #endregion

                secondAtom.parentMolecule = molecule;
                moleculeData.centralAtom.AddConnectedAtom(secondAtom);
                secondAtom.AddConnectedAtom(moleculeData.centralAtom);

                molecule.AddAtoms(moleculeData.centralAtom, secondAtom);
                molecule.AddBond(bond);
                //update reactive spots, since we added new bond
                moleculeData.centralAtom.RemoveReactiveSpots(bond);
                secondAtom.RemoveReactiveSpots(bond);
                secondAtomTransform.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> All of this is working properly but their occurs some cases when some
>   atoms overlap each other despite having rigid body attached to them..

I looked very close at your code and saw this:

```
secondAtomTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
secondAtomTransform.position = finalAtomTwoPos;
```

Don't do that. That's not how to properly rotate or move a Rigidbody. Since this is just part of your code, get ride of any code where you are moving or rotating Rigidbody Object with `Transform.position` or `Transform.localRotation`.

Rigibody should be moved with the [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) function and rotated with the [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) function.

---

While I expect this to work, if the problem still occur then change the Rigidbody's Interpolate to from *None* to *Interpolate*. Another thing to do is to change the Rigidbody's *Collision Detection* to *continuous*.

Comment: I had access to the transform component, so I fetched rigidbody from it and then called movePosition method. I checked using Logs but it returns same position before and after moving. I also changed interpolate and collision as you said but nothing changed

Comment: Also these methods are not called in Update or FIxedUpdate method. These are called from Leap Motion callback methods so I think that is the issue that MovePosition is not working

Comment: To be honest with you `MovePosition` should fix the issue you described in this question. I do suggest you create an empty project and study how to use it. I think you have to redesign/rewrite your app code to work with `MovePosition`. It sucks but that seems like a good way to go.

Comment: `secondAtomTransform.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(finalAtomTwoPos)`. This is how I called the method. Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes. So, what's the problem? Is the overlapping still happening?

Comment: MovePosition doesn't changes the position. I logged both positions before and after moving both were same.

Comment: but one strange thing I noticed. `secondAtomTransform.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position` and `secondAtomTransform.position` returns different values.

Comment: This is why I told you to create a simple new scene with a new test script. Create an object with a rigidbody then try to move it this way and see what happens. If it works then you moving that object from multiple places.

Comment: I will try and let you know after that